# modifying tibbles inside of a list of tibbles (and secondarily filtering list of tibbles by dimensional size)

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to cleanup some **scraped** data.

```
a <-  read_html("Top Ten FRANKREICH 2021_2.html")  %>%    html_nodes("table") %>%   html_table()
#a <- read_html("https://www.insidekino.de/BO/F2021.htm")  %>%    html_nodes("table") %>%   html_table()
a2 <- a[30:42] #list of 13 [13x6 dataframes]
```

##tangent: is there a way to filter by tibble size in the sublist? I'm manually selecting all 13x6 tibbles but there has to be a way to automate this
b <- data.table::rbindlist(a2)
##I've added some very minor language translations to table below so recreating this will give you slightly different content in rows 2 & 3

What I want to do is to mutate row 1 ("weekend #") into another column, and make the second row column names. I get how to do this as stand alone dataframes but I'm struggling to figure out how to approach it when stuck in a list of tibbles. Once I bind all the rows together, I'm presumably too late as I couldn't add a week ID tag to rows.

| X1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| Weekend Rank | weekend. | % | total. | Week_number. | Film |
| 1 | 490.984 | +63 | 870.117 | 2 | Cruella |
| 2 | 434.523 | --- | 434.523 | 1 | Peter Hase 2 |
| 3 | 306.453 | +41 | 1.661.962 | 4 | Conjuring 3 |
| 4 | 244.444 | --- | 244.444 | 1 | Le Sens de la famille |
| 5 | 213.699 | --- | 213.699 | 1 | Présidents |
| 6 | 190.352 | --- | 190.352 | 1 | Killer's Bodyguard 2 |
| 7 | 176.120 | +45 | 323.826 | 2 | Opération Portugal |
| 8 | 174.470 | +56 | 547.384 | 3 | A Quiet Place 2 |
| 9 | 130.691 | --- | 130.691 | 1 | The Deep House |
| 10 | 127.082 | +51 | 381.308 | 3 | Cash Truck |
| 2.488.818 | +106 | 8.726.195 | 27 | Weekly_total |  |
| Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |

and preferred outcome

| Weekend Rank | Weekend Gross | % | total. | Week_number. | Film | Weekend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 490.984 | 63 | 870.117 | 2 | Cruella | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 2 | 434.523 | --- | 434.523 | 1 | Peter Hase 2 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 3 | 306.453 | 41 | 1.661.962 | 4 | Conjuring 3 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 4 | 244.444 | --- | 244.444 | 1 | Le Sens de la famille | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 5 | 213.699 | --- | 213.699 | 1 | Présidents | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 6 | 190.352 | --- | 190.352 | 1 | Killer's Bodyguard 2 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 7 | 176.12 | 45 | 323.826 | 2 | Opération Portugal | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 8 | 174.47 | 56 | 547.384 | 3 | A Quiet Place 2 | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 9 | 130.691 | --- | 130.691 | 1 | The Deep House | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 10 | 127.082 | 51 | 381.308 | 3 | Cash Truck | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
|  | 2.488.818 | 106 | 8.726.195 | 27 | Weekly_total | Weekend 27: 30.6.2021 - 4.7.2021 |
| 1 | 702.553 | -- | 702.553 | 1 | Black Widow | Weekend 28: 7.7.2021 - 11.7.2021 |
| … | … | … | … | … | … | … |

Comment: FYI it's __scraped__ (and __scrape__, __scraping__, __scraper__) not scrapped. 'Scrapped' means thrown away like rubbish :-o

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result is by making use of `purrr::keep` to filter the list, use map to clean up the tables and finally bind them by rows:

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

a <- read_html("https://www.insidekino.de/BO/F2021.htm")  %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table() 

b <- a %>% 
  purrr::keep(~ nrow(.x) == 13) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ mutate(.x, weekend = .x[[1,1]]) %>% 
        slice(-1) %>% 
        janitor::row_to_names(1) %>% 
        rename(weekend = 7)) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()

b
#> # A tibble: 143 × 7
#>    Nr.   Bes.    `%`   Ges.      Wo.   Film                  weekend            
#>    <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr>                 <chr>              
#>  1 1     490.984 +63   870.117   2     Cruella               Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  2 2     434.523 ---   434.523   1     Peter Hase 2          Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  3 3     306.453 +41   1.661.962 4     Conjuring 3           Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  4 4     244.444 ---   244.444   1     Le Sens de la famille Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  5 5     213.699 ---   213.699   1     Présidents            Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  6 6     190.352 ---   190.352   1     Killer's Bodyguard 2  Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  7 7     176.120 +45   323.826   2     Opération Portugal    Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  8 8     174.470 +56   547.384   3     A Quiet Place 2       Wochenende 27: 30.…
#>  9 9     130.691 ---   130.691   1     The Deep House        Wochenende 27: 30.…
#> 10 10    127.082 +51   381.308   3     Cash Truck            Wochenende 27: 30.…
#> # … with 133 more rows
```

Comment: Ah, that's fantastic

Comment: Unrelated followup: you'll see that "Admissions/Bes." uses periods as a marker to divide thousands. How do we get this this to be read as commas. I don't think multiplying everything by 1000 would work.

Comment: Nop. As the columns are characters multiplying by 1000 will not work. One option would be to replace the `.` by comma using e.g. `gsub` or `string::str_replace` or remove them altogether if you want to convert to numeric.